# Drill Down on a Zero Value in an SSRS Bar Chart

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a bar chart in SSRS that does legitimately produce zero values.  Is it possible in SSRS to drill down on the zero values like you can with non-zero values?  The action on the data series works great for all values other than zero.

Comment: By "zero values" do you meant count(values) = 0 or a bunch of zeroes (0,0,0,0)?

Comment: The problem is that you don't have a bar to click on for the to drill-through, correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  No bar to select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The zero values still have a clickable link, it's right on the axis (or at zero).  Not easy to find or to click but it does work.

Answer (score 0):

What about a range chart? The range chart takes **dates as values**, so depending on how your data is **grouped** as long as they have a **date associatead** with it they will map out and then you can drill through.  You might even be able to add dates yourself.

The only thing you have to watch out for it that the range chart takes in a **range of dates** so you need **two**.  But you can always do a **dateadd aggregate function** to produce another column and that could be your **second date value**.

Let me know if this helps, Cheers!

Comment: I like the idea but the layout is decided by the users not me.